# Last.fm playlist manager

Tags: playlists, last.fm

Is there such a thing as a Last.fm playlist creator/manager?

Either an online web application or desktop (Linux and/or OS X) would be fine.  Managing playlists through Last.fm's web site is, shall we say, painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to find a decent playlist manager for last.fm, have a look at [this Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/32963), though.